# How to change the content of a option Tag with it's id?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This should be a easy question but I can't get through it, so I need your help.

I have four option tag in my select structure and each tag has a value and id and content like this:-

```html
<select id='0'>
      ABC
      <option id='123' value='X'>ABC</option>
      <option id='456' value='Y'>DEF</option>
    </select>
```

My question is, how can I change the content of the option Tag by it's id later? I can't select the specific option tag with it's value because I can only get the id with a series of complicated functions.

To be more clear:- I have the id of a option tag and I need to change the content, "ABC", "DEF", the value is used for other things and I can't select the option tag with the value.

Thank you all!

Comment: have you tried?  `$('#id').html('ABC');`

Comment: yes i have tried all the things i can find here, except the .attr way. i don't know the the .html didn't work for me.

Comment: Mr.@Min XIE .. see my answer which is updated just now ...

Comment: Like @Jana said you should use the `text()` method - See the fiddle https://fiddle.jshell.net/o08pazj5/ (sets all options text but easy to address an individual one)

Answer (score 0):

It should works perfectly!!

`$('select #id').text('ABC');`

`$('select option#id').text('ABC');`

`jquery` has different approach for change the content of `option` only as said as `text()`. Then remaining all `html` tags can use `html()` for change content.
  Then i have selected the `option` which has `specific_id` by  `$('select option#specific_id')`

Comment: Isn't this is a kind of comment?

Comment: sorry..i forgot

Comment: THANKS!! i have tried it and it works, but it will be so nice if u can tell me how to use a variable for the id. I get the id with a series of complicated functions and it's a variable. I have already tried ur method but i can only type the id manually, how can i select the option tag with a variable id.

Comment: @MinXIE `var id=123; $('select #' + id).text('ABC')` this will do.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function(){
$('select option[id="123"]').text('xyz');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id='0'>
      <option id='123' value='X'>ABC</option>
      <option id='456' value='Y'>DEF</option>
    </select>
```

just like this:

Comment: Can you pls tell me what should i do when my id is a variable? I know it works, i have tried, but my id is a variable.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Imagine you have optionId as variable
var optionId = '456';

// Get related option element
var relatedOption = $('#select option[id=' + optionId + ']');

// Change its value and its text
relatedOption.val(relatedOption.attr('value')).text(relatedOption.attr('value'))
```